# How to implement a Snake Game with multiple "food" with a linked list? (Java)

Tags: java, linked-list, coordinates

Currently, my snake game has only one food that spawns at a random coordinate and disappears and spawns at another coordinate when the snake's head touches it. I want to add multiple foods at the same time, with the food that is touched disappearing and spawning elsewhere but the other foods stay where they are. I'm using a linked list of Coordinates for both the snake and the food. This works fine for the snake, because it only has to add onto the head and remove the last Coordinate, but it doesn't work so well with food. The food pellets are scattered around the grid, so the snake could touch any one of them, whether they are the head, in the middle somewhere, or the tail. If it's just one food it would be food = new Coordinate() which assigns it a random coordinate in the grid but with multiple food in a linked list, I don't know how to identify which food was touched  so that I can make that one disappear and respawn.

Answer (score 1):

You can have 2 `lists`. One for the snake, and one for the food.
Then you can search the Food list, to find the food (if any) that has the same coordinates as the head of the snake.

However the "correct" data structure for the snake, would be a `Queue`(the tail would be the first element, and the head would be the last), and for the food would be a `Hashmap`. That way you can find the food in O(1) complexity time.
That is, if the number of `Food` spots would be a lot. If not, a `list` would work just fine.